# How can I use jsDoc with mobx-state-tree?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc, mobx-state-tree

I am trying to use jsDoc for my mobx-state-tree powered app but it does not react the way I want.

Visual studio code does not show me the right properties of the corresponding type:

[image: vs-code lists wrong properties]

jsDoc is a huge help when it comes to refactoring and keeping js code bug free! But how can I make use of it in this case?

I found this, but it seems it's not really used by anyone: 
https://github.com/Feverqwe/mst-jsdoc-gen

I really wonder how other devs are dealing with this!

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: No, i am not. And I don't want to migrate my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your jsDoc is not referring to the instance of the type, but to the type itself.

Try this instead:

```
/**
 * @param {typeof Step.Type} step
 */
async applyStep(step){}
```

Or this (as pointed out in the typescript section of the [docs](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#using-a-mst-type-at-design-time)):

```
/**
 * @param {Instance<typeof Step>} step
 */
async applyStep(step){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project may be missing a `jsconfig.json` that [defines it to be a Javascript project to Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_why-do-i-need-a-jsconfigjson-file).

For example, given project tree

```
.
├── jsconfig.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── step.js
│   └── test.js
└── yarn.lock
```

In `jsconfig.json` is defined the following,

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es6"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
}
```

`allowSyntheticDefaultImports` configuration is important because it allows code hints for symbols that are not exported in Javascript modules in the project.

[image: Showing code hints upon adding jsconfig.json]

To get type hints of a mobx state tree model, one could explicitly document `typedef`. For example,

```
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree"


const Step = types.model({
    level: types.number,
    strength: types.number
})

 /**
 * @typedef Step
 * @property {Number} level
 * @property {Number} strength
 */
```

[image: type hints for mobx-state-tree models after typedef]

I reckon that one could go a step further to write a hook that dynamically generates this `typedef` documentation for models.

I'm not aware of a tool that does this right off the bat.

You could fork the tool you shared, update it then [configure a custom task in Visual Studio Code to run it](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) whenever models are updated.

Comment: The problem is not that code completion is not working, the problem is that it's showing the wrong completion results (see screenshot). This is very much related to mobx-state-tree (other code works perfectly fine)

Comment: You are correct. I think the closest you can get is either explicitly documenting the type definitions by hand or an updated version of the tool you shared together with a custom task in vscode to automate the process.